# General question about totalSupply: fixed since first moment (aka Bitcoin) or indefinite (aka Ethereum)?

Tags: tokens, mining, contract-deployment

In an answer to a general question about totalSupply, I gave some rough indication about the aim of token deployer vs totalSupply: [Why is the totalSupply of this token statically initialized to 5500000000?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64855/why-is-the-totalsupply-of-this-token-statically-initialized-to-5500000000/64857#64857)

But now I was asking myself if there exists a true crypto economic rationale criteria that can be used.

Does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the currencies is deflationary and the other is inflationary. These come from the Austrian and Keynesian schools of economic though. In the former (Bitcoin like) the price of the currency is expected to grow as apposite to the second.

There is a nací articule where Bitcoin is compared to Fiat on the views of this schools of thought. This may help to see the property and cons of them.

https://www.investinblockchain.com/bitcoin-is-a-deflationary-currency/amp/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your point is appreciable, thank you. I understand that may be that a true operative answer to my question may not exist yet.